# Problem with left rear axle on crashed 2003 Honda Pilot

Tags: honda, axle, pilot, rear

The other night I slid my car into a curb after sliding on ice, I am not quite sure what I did to my back left wheel and axle. Please help me figure out what new parts I need.

I have attached pictures of the damage below. I know a lot of the photos are extremely similar.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

[image: Image 4]

[image: Image 5]

[image: Image 6]

Comment: It's really difficult to tell what's going on from these photos.  I assume that the wheel is pointing in a direction that it's not supposed do point but I'm just guessing on that.  Probably you broke or bent one or more of the parts.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Your best bet is to search online for a complete rear suspension through a wrecking yard. I'd look at replacing  at a minimum, all of the parts associated with the suspension on that side of the vehicle (upper/lower control arms, knuckle, drive axle). And if I were actually doing it, I'd replace the subframe complete, as it would overall be easier and take less time. If you can find it used as a complete unit, you'll save yourself a TON of money. You really don't know what's actually tweaked under there, so it's hard to tell otherwise.

Comment: Can you add a photo of where the driveshaft goes into the differential.

Comment: The right and left side drive and suspension are mirror images of each other. Did you examine the right side for comparison?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that it's at least the highlighted part.  This is the "trailing arm" and it's what keeps the wheel pointing in the right direction.  It appears from the photos that this part is bent or broken and is allowing the wheel to flop over.

Unless you are familiar with working on suspension parts, I recommend that you have this towed to a shop as there is very likely other damage and it all needs to be checked for damage and replaced if necessary.

[image: Honda Pilot Rear Suspension]

Comment: Thank you for the help, I have added some more photos that may help.

Answer (score 0):

The lower front arm is definitely bent.  You can see it in this photo -

[image]

That curve shouldn’t be there.

I would also check where it mounts to the subframe, because there could be damage there -

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I added a photo where you can clearly see that it is bent badly

Comment: @GuyWithProblems That is pretty impressive.  It looks like the bolt hole in the bracket may be damaged to.

Comment: @GuyWithProblems with that sort of damage, I wouldn’t be surprised if your wheel is bent too.

Comment: how much do you think the car is worth if sold for parts?

Comment: @GuyWithProblems I wouldn’t have a clue, sorry.